# How can i sort order of wordcount with Python?

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.8, word-count

I am using this code to count the same words in a text file.

```
filename = input("Enter name of input file: ")
file = open(filename, "r", encoding="utf8")
wordCounter = {}
with open(filename,'r',encoding="utf8") as fh:
  for line in fh:
    # Replacing punctuation characters. Making the string to lower.
    # The split will spit the line into a list.
    word_list = line.replace(',','').replace('\'','').replace('.','').replace("'",'').replace('"','').replace('"','').replace('#','').replace('!','').replace('^','').replace('$','').replace('+','').replace('%','').replace('&','').replace('/','').replace('{','').replace('}','').replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('(','').replace(')','').replace('=','').replace('*','').replace('?','').lower().split()
    for word in word_list:
      # Adding  the word into the wordCounter dictionary.
      if word not in wordCounter:
        wordCounter[word] = 1
      else:
        # if the word is already in the dictionary update its count.
        wordCounter[word] = wordCounter[word] + 1

print('{:15}{:3}'.format('Word','Count'))
print('-' * 18)
# printing the words and its occurrence.
for  word,occurance  in wordCounter.items():
  print(word,occurance)
```

I need them to be in order in bigger number to smaller number as output. For example:

word 1: 25

word 2: 12

word 3: 5
.
.
.

I also need to get the input as just ".txt" file. If the user writes anything different the program must get an error as "Write a valid file name".

How can i sort output and make the error code at the same time ?

Comment: input which is entered must end with".txt". The main goal here is not to allow anything else. The name is not important.

Comment: Why don't you use the `Counter` class from `collections`? It is faster, and it even has a `most_common` method which sorts the elements just as you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For printing in order, you can sort them prior to printing by the occurrence like this:

```py
for  word,occurance  in sorted(wordCounter.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
  print(word,occurance)
```

In order to check whether the file is valid in the way that you want, you can consider using:

```py
import os

path1 = "path/to/file1.txt"
path2 = "path/to/file2.png"

if not path1.lower().endswith('.txt'):
    print("Write a valid file name")

if not os.path.exists(path1):
    print("File does not exists!")
```

Comment: That works very well thank you so much. Do you have any idea how can i write the error code ?

Comment: @plluviophille Added to the answer. I would suggest using some checks like whether the file exists too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and also for suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
if ( filename[-4:0] != '.txt'):
    print('Please input a valid file name')
```

And repeat input command...